# Segmentation fault in array defined function

Tags: function, module, fortran, gfortran

When I am using a fortran function defined with an array and trying to access the function inside another routine, that is giving segmentation fault. Below is my code.

```
module abcd
implicit none
contains

real*8 function f(x)
real*8,intent(in)::x(:)
f=sum(x)
end function f

real*8 function funco(f,n)
real*8,external::f
integer,intent(in)::n  !dimension of array to be used with f
real*8::y(n)
y=1
funco=f(y)
end function funco

end module abcd


use abcd
implicit none

write(*,*) funco(f,10)
end
```

Here, I have explicitly defined the array y inside funco, still segmentation fault is coming. My original program is required to use a function that behaves like the function funco. I gave this small example for demonstrating my issue.

Comment: The function `f` has a dummy argument of assumed shape, but in `funco` you say that the dummy function has an implicit interface. That's not allowed. Do you know about interfaces?

Comment: Not actually, never used those.

Comment: If you want to use that module function `f` in the function `funco` you'll need to provide an explicit interface for `f` in `funco`; if you want to use `external f` in `funco` you'll need to make the module function `f` suitable to be used with an implicit interface. There's more detail in the linked question and its answers, but a wider search for "explicit interface" will provide many other questions/answers.

Comment: Be aware that explicit interface is not a piece of code with the `interface` keyword. It is a concept denoting that the calling code can see the description of the subroutine or function.